# how to pick aggregates for grouping sets in postgres?

Tags: post

Actually, i think no can do but here it is

```sql
SELECT a,sum(b),min(b),max(b)
FROM atable 
group by rollup(1)
```

now I want null to be displayed instead for rollup min/max

| A | sum | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'a' | 6 | 6 | 7 |
| 'a' | 7 | 6 | 7 |
| NULL | 13 | NULL | NULL |

is this possible?

Comment: What if agg1 is null?

Comment: then null 
the requirement is do not rollup agg2 or agg3